# Why is "remate" used for taking a shot in football?

Tags: verbos, etimología, expresiones

Since the verb **[*Rematar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VsRrsFs)** consists of *re + matar*, and most of the definitions concerning it define it as either "finishing off" or completing a sale, how did it come to be used in Football as *remate* when a team sets up and takes a shot at the goal?

Is there an etymology to explain this usage?

Comment: Aparte de _remate_, en español hay un montón de metáforas de la guerra en el deporte: cañonero, capitán, justa deportiva, tiro, disparo, la armada española, estocada, escuadra, retaguardia, contraataque, el Bombardero Valenciano, el Matador Salas, Cañoncito Pum, el Misil Restrepo, el Tanque Pavone, el Torpedo Muller, el Rifle Pandiani...

Comment: @Rodrigo muy interesante, y merece ser ampliado como respuesta. Graciás por su comentario.

Comment: De nada, pero la verdad no amerita como respuesta porque me he dado cuenta de que _rematar_ ya tiene el significado de "terminar" tan atrás como en el año 1220, según el Diccionario Etimológico de Corominas. O sea que realmente nadie está pensando en "matar" cuando patea una pelota (y los ejemplos del comentario anterior solo quedan como curiosidad). Puede ser, en cambio, que el inglés _shot_ sí sea una metáfora bélica.

Comment: I don't really get the question. You say that *rematar* is *finishing off*, but seem to be asking why in football the word *rematar* is used for finishing off a play. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Gorpik "Finishing off" as in the _tiro de gracia_, literally killing. I didn't draw a connection, but perhaps someone who has been listening to football matches all their life has never seen any incongruity in that.

Comment: Well, it was obvious I had misunderstood you somehow. Then @Rodrigo's comment should be enough: the verb *rematar* has had this meaning of finishing things for many centuries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rematar` has several meanings, one of them is shooting at the goal in football. It's even there in the link you posted:

> 8. tr. En el fútbol y otros deportes, dar término a una serie de jugadas lanzando el balón hacia la meta contraria.

Of course like in many other examples, there are synonyms for that word:

> Tirar, lanzar, patear, chutar *(in some countries this is used as `chutear`)*

Are perfectly valid synonyms for the same word.

So you can say either:

> El jugador no consiguió **rematar** a portería durante todo el tiempo que estuvo en la cancha, por lo que no fue sorpresa que lo cambiaran en el segundo tiempo.
>
> El jugador no consiguió **tirar** a portería durante todo el tiempo que estuvo en la cancha, por lo que no fue sorpresa que lo cambiaran en el segundo tiempo.
>
> El jugador no consiguió **lanzar** a portería durante todo el tiempo que estuvo en la cancha, por lo que no fue sorpresa que lo cambiaran en el segundo tiempo.

I have found an [article in the Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_del_f%C3%BAtbol#Edad_Media) where they talk about the origins of football. In the beginning it was a very violent game, so I believe the terms of `shooting` is because of this extremly violent game, where the rivals were seen as sort of enemies. It was kind of a little war I believe, so maybe that's the origin of the usage of those words in football.

Comment: I know it's in the link, but I am wondering about _how_ this became a usage. It has only the one definition for a particular sport. I have never seen a football match in English, and have no idea what the equivalent expression would be. Is it like "going in for the kill"?

Comment: In english is `shoot`. In spanish you can even say `disparar a portería`. I have heard sometimes in a football match where they say `misilazo` for referring to a powerful shot. I have found a nice article, I will update my answer.

Comment: @Gandalf The interpretation is something like this: when the player closes to the goal, the goalkeeper is already dead, because the score is imminet. Hence, the shot is called *remate* because it's like killing twice the goalkeeper.

Comment: muy amable, graciás.

Comment: @Ustanak That sounds closer to the second definition in RAE, thanks. I'm more of a nerd than a jock, and only watch during the regionals and world cups, but I have often wondered.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. As I live in one of the countries where it is believed the American version of the sport originated, you would think I would have the sense of this, but I didn't.

Comment: Also note that in Portuguese, *rematar* is the most common word for *to shoot* in sports (I generally use *chutar* — Peninsular Spanish). It's quite possible that Spanish adopted it from Portuguese (or could be the other way around), as the sports meaning definitely would have developed long after the languages split.

Comment: The problem with some of these suggestions is that they are all very violent and war-like whereas most of the meanings in the DRAE entry are more neutral (especially the meaning to tie off a thread).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's case of shift in meaning. A series of plays approaching the goal would reach its conclusion ([`remate`](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VsSaDkI)) with a shoot to goal. Later, the meaning shifted to any hard hit or shoot that could win in the play. Nowadays it's used with that meaning in almost every ball sport.